# Can you explain how function can be smooth but not finite valued?

Tags: functional-analysis

I was reading Kurdyka-Lojasiewicz property in a paper and the made an assumption that f must be smooth and finite valued. I am wondering if one can you explain how function can be smooth but not finite valued?
I know a function is finite value if it return values only in $\mathbb{R}$ for all $\mathbb{R}$, but it might be unbounded.

I would appreciate your help in advance

Comment: $f(x )=x^2$, $f(x)=e^x$, ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe These functions you provided are unbounded but they are finite in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Amir How is “finite in $\mathbb R$” defined?

Comment: By " $f$ is finite-valued " do they mean that $\forall y ( \{ x : f(x)=y\}$ is a finite set) ?